# How to create table and populate from data in any cell

Tags: json, angular, html-table, row, multiple-columns

I have a question, How to create a table in html like in image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g5Dg.png)

Table populate with data in JSON.

Response from ws is:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 0,
    "ErrorMessage": "ok",
    "Data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "pump": 1,
            "nozzle": 0,
            "totalVolume": 46285.22
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "pump": 1,
            "nozzle": 1,
            "totalVolume": 8317.66
        },
        {
             "id": 8,
             "pump": 1,
            "nozzle": 2,
            "totalVolume": 10541.3
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "pump": 1,
            "nozzle": 3,
            "totalVolume": 3010.69
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "pump": 2,
            "nozzle": 0,
            "totalVolume": 21319.66
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "pump": 2,
            "nozzle": 1,
            "totalVolume": 7521.39
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "pump": 2,
            "nozzle": 2,
            "totalVolume": 8473.6
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "pump": 2,
            "nozzle": 3,
            "totalVolume": 1827.56
        }
    ]
}
```

Please I need your help, how to create this table and in any cell populate with totalValue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to loop 2 times your list. The first one in which you can display your columns. And the second one for the rows.

At least you can also modify your Json structure creating one array containing your column values and the second one your row values